# How do I get gradle to update .gradle/caches from my local .m2 repository?

Tags: gradle

I have a common project built with gradle.  When I do a `gradle clean install` it installs the newest .jar file in my local .m2 repository.  The .gradle/caches still contains the old version of the library, however, which is what gradle and Intellij uses.  This prevents me from testing the changes I've made to the common library locally.

Using `--refresh-dependencies` doesn't help because it pulls the old version from a remote repository instead of from my .m2 repo.  I had to manually copy the new library file from my .m2 repository to .gradle/caches in order to test the changes.

Maybe there is a use case where having a local .m2 repository and a cache makes sense, but it doesn't for testing library changes locally.  Is there a way to get gradle to install the new version in .gradle/caches so I can test my changes before publishing them to our repository?